# How to update sharepoint online list data via excel

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

my client has a requirement that he should be able to update the sharepoint list data from Excel sheet but in Sharepoint only one way data sync. is possible (we can import the data in excel but we can not update sharepoint list via excel).

Comment: check this question from Sharepoint stackechange.. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34433/update-sharepoint-list-using-excel

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead - if SharePoint list data is below the threshold limit of 5000 records, then perhaps you can use datasheet view of list

Comment: True.. but client wants to update it via excel only.